# Why is Jack Sparrow looking for the drawing of the key?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

At the start of *Dead Man's Chest,* Jack Sparrow escapes the Turkish prison with the drawing of the key to the chest. But this happens *before* Bootstrap Bill comes to warn Jack that Davy Jones is out to make good on their deal. Sure, Jack knew this day would come, but he seems surprised and tries to talk his way out of it. Why had he already taken the first steps to get out of his debt to Jones?

Comment: Maybe he came sooner than expected?

Comment: Jack is always trying to break out of prison. His hobbies include, but are not limited to: Rum, Booty, and Breaking out of jail.

Comment: I'm not surprised that he broke out of jail, but there's a line where Gibbs makes it clear that Jack went into the prison specifically to retrieve the drawing of the key

Answer (score 2):

This is just my view of it, but it seems that Jack did know that it was about time that Mr. Tentacles would come to collect. It would also explain why he was so keen on getting the Black Pearl back in the first movie. Supposedly, it is one of the few ships fast enough to outrun the Dutchman and maybe even the Kraken.

The Aztec treasure that he searched for could've also been a way to squirrel out of the deal somehow. But when he saw what really happens to those who take the gold, he would have decided that getting to the heart is a better way.

After getting the Pearl back from Barbosa, he went after the key.

Like I said, this is mostly speculation and guesswork based on what I know of the movies. I could be utterly wrong as well.

Comment: There's something here that makes sense, and is definitely consistent with the admirable way in which Elliott & Rossio recontextualized things from the first movie in order to create the appearance of a cohesive trilogy. That being said, it still strikes me as too convenient. The heart would've been his main priority in the first movie. And if the Black Pearl could outrun either the Dutchman or the Kraken there'd be no need for the key that unlocks the chest that holds the heart.

Comment: @user30903 Like I said, it's all just speculation and guesswork and won't actually hold up under scrutiny.

Comment: Just think how fast the Black Pearl would have been with new sails.